# How to authorize username and password for post java rest service

Tags: ios, objective-c

Here is the Url I am trying to hit using post method for the jave rest webservice

```
http://10.222.0.100:8080/CRM/rest/user/login?id=amit&password=amit123 // demo
```

Below is the code That I using to hit the services

```
NSError* error;
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self makeURLStringForRequest]]; //http://10.222.0.100:8080/CRM/rest/user/login
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    if (self.requestDict!=nil)
    {

NSData* dataToSet = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.requestDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];// dict:{ id:"amit" , password="amit123" }
if (error==nil)
{
    [request setHTTPBody:dataToSet];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[dataToSet length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

}
    }
    error=nil;
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error==nil && [data length]>0)
     {
         [[Data_Manager getInstanse]processData:data withRequestType:self.requestType andDelegate:self.delegate];
     }
     else
     {
          NSLog(@"%@",error);
         if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didfailWithError:)])
         {
             [self.delegate didfailWithError:error];
         }
     }
 }];
}
```

But it always returning fail , could anyone please let me know what's wrong with the code.

if I hit the whole url in browser it returing true.

```
http://10.222.0.100:8080/CRM/rest/user/login?id=amit&password=amit123 // demo
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using UNIRest for interacting with RESTful APIs in Objective-C. You can get it here: https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-obj-c

After you add it to your project, you can send your request like this:

```
[[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *simpleRequest) {
    [simpleRequest setUrl:@"http://10.222.0.100:8080/CRM/rest/user/login"];
    [simpleRequest setHeaders:@{@"accept": @"application/json"}];
    [simpleRequest setParameters:@{@"id": @"amit", @"password": @"amit123"}];
}] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse *jsonResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[jsonResponse body] JSONObject]);
}];
```

Edit: You should also note that if writing that URL in your browser and hitting enter gets you the response you want as you have stated, then you might actually need to send the data with GET instead of POST. In which case the above code simply becomes:

```
[[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest *simpleRequest) {
    [simpleRequest setUrl:@"http://10.222.0.100:8080/CRM/rest/user/login"];
    [simpleRequest setHeaders:@{@"accept": @"application/json"}];
    [simpleRequest setParameters:@{@"id": @"amit", @"password": @"amit123"}];
}] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse *jsonResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[jsonResponse body] JSONObject]);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This i used same for java rest service it worked

```
-(void)tryThis  
{  
NSString *a=@"{'login' : 'sdsd', 'password' : 'sdsd'}";    
a= [a stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange (0, [a length])];

or
NSString *a=@"{"login" : "sdsd", "password" : "sdsd"}"; 

NSData* postData= [a dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];  
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:***********your url"]];  
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];  
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];   
[request setHTTPBody:postData];  
NSURLResponse *response = NULL;   
NSError *requestError = NULL;   
NSData *responseData1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&requestError];   
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
 }
```